# Facebook C# SDK version 5.2.1 sample code to post to User wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK version 5.2.1 in Iframe App. I want to post something like images, links or videos to User Wall.

Is it possible to do the same using javascript SDK?

Please refer some sample codes or links that i can use for C# or javascript SDK..

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
   name: 'Connect',
   caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
      description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
   actions: [
        { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/' }
   ],
  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```